# Salvando Imagem base64 com ADODB.Stream

Tags: imagem, asp, stream-de-arquivos

Após converter uma image para base64 utilizando html5 e canvas, envio a string para o ASP Clássico e lá devo salvar esta imagem em um determinado diretório.
Estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
    base64String = Trim(Request.Form("base64"))

    Set tmpDoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
    Set nodeB64 = tmpDoc.CreateElement("b64")
    nodeB64.DataType = "bin.base64"
    nodeB64.Text = Mid(base64String, InStr(base64String, ",") + 1)

    set bStream = server.CreateObject("ADODB.stream")

    bStream.type = adTypeBinary

    call bStream.Open()

    call bStream.Write(nodeB64.NodeTypedValue)

    call bStream.SaveToFile("C:\fotos\imagem.jpg", adSaveCreateOverWrite)

    call bStream.close()
    set bStream = nothing
```

O cliente está desta forma:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="base64" name="base64" value="" />
</form>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var c = document.getElementById("c");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    c.width = 50;
    c.height = 50;

    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 50);

    $("#base64").val(c.toDataURL(files[0].type));
</script>
```

O objetivo é redimensionar a imagem, gerar o código base64 e enviar para o servidor. No servidor eu converto o base64 em imagem e salvo ela em um diretório específico.
Está tudo certo se não fosse pelo fato de estar gravando uma imagem preta.
Percebi que a imagem original tem 1.406 bytes e após salvar fica com 691 bytes.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Grato.

Comment: Já que os arquivos são pequenos, tem como postar um hex dump do arquivo original e do arquivo corrompido?

Comment: Seu files[0].type ta retornando o que no javascript quando tu executa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onaiggac eu tentei usar o seu código, porém este servidor que eu uso não é tecnologia microsoft e faz muito tempo que não trabalho com servidor asp-classic, mas pelos poucos testes que fiz o problema parece ser no front-end e não no back-end.

De qualquer forma eu modifiquei o código (para funcionar no meu servidor local), troquei isto `bStream.type = adTypeBinary` por `bStream.type = 1` e  `bStream.SaveToFile("C:\fotos\imagem.jpg", adSaveCreateOverWrite)` por `bStream.SaveToFile("C:\ASP\www\imagem.jpg", 2)`, não acho que faça diferença, mas não custa testar

O código completo ficou assim (funcionou perfeitamente):

**save.asp**

```
<%
base64String = Trim(Request.Form("base64"))

Set tmpDoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
Set nodeB64 = tmpDoc.CreateElement("b64")
nodeB64.DataType = "bin.base64"
nodeB64.Text = Mid(base64String, InStr(base64String, ",") + 1)

set bStream = server.CreateObject("ADODB.stream")

bStream.type = 1

call bStream.Open()

call bStream.Write(nodeB64.NodeTypedValue)

call bStream.SaveToFile("C:\ASP\www\imagem.jpg", 2)

call bStream.close()
set bStream = nothing
%>
```

Funcionou perfeitamente, usei um HTML de exemplo:

**form.asp**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ido-8859-1">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="save.asp">
    <textarea name="base64">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</textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

<s>Se este código funcionar para ti então realmente o problema é no front-end e você deverá editar a sua pergunta e adicionar o html e javascript (acredito que seja algo com canvas que você esteja manipulando)</s>

### Atualização

Efetuei o teste, o problema ocorre quando você envia `data:image/jpeg;base64,` junto, você deve usar `String.replace` para remover isto e deixar apenas o base64, o seu código deveria ficar algo como:

```
$("#base64").val(c.toDataURL(files[0].type).replace(/^data[:]image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, ""));
```

Um exemplo funcional seria:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ido-8859-1">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="save.asp">
    <textarea name="base64" id="base64"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<img id="i" src="15258056.png">
<canvas id="c"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var base64 = document.getElementById("base64");
    var img = document.getElementById("i");
    var c = document.getElementById("c");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    c.width = 50;
    c.height = 50;

    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 50);

    base64.value = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace(/^data[:]image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Atualização 2

Apesar de não estar no escopo da pergunta, o autor detectou o problema, era com o `FileReader`. O `FileReader` necessita do evento `onload` antes de iniciar o envio para o servidor, um exemplo de como deve ficar o código:

**JavaScript:**

```
function getImage() {
    var file   = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            resizeImage(img);
        };
        img.src = reader.result;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function resizeImage(img) {
    var base64 = document.getElementById("base64");
    var c = document.getElementById("c");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    c.width = 50;
    c.height = 50;

    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 50);

    base64.value = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace(/^data[:]image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("file").onchange = getImage;
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<style type="text/css">
#c {
    border: 1px #c0c0c0 solid;
}
</style>

<input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*">
<form method="POST" action="save.asp">
    <textarea name="base64" id="base64"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Adicionei o código front-end que estou utilizando. Alterei meu código back-end como o proposto mas o resultado foi o mesmo.

Comment: @Onaiggac atualizei a resposta, veja se lhe ajuda.

Comment: A linha Mid(base64String, InStr(base64String, ",") + 1) já tem o propósito de remover aquele início.

Comment: Consegui resolver. A rotina js e asp estavam todas certas, porém eu executava a rotina js num momento errado. Eu tenho que executar dentro do método onload do objeto FileReader. Vou considerar sua resposta como certa por ter colocado um exemplo completo e funcional.

Comment: @Onaiggac Otimo trabalho, parabéns por ter encontrado o problema sozinho e obrigado pela gratificação. Note que eu editei a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Já tentou trocar</strike>

```
Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
Set nodeB64 = tmpDoc.CreateElement("b64")
```

por

```
Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
Set nodeB64 = tmpDoc.CreateElement("base64")
```

E em último caso

```
bStream.charSet = "us-ascii"
bStream.position = 0
```

Tenta:

```
' type binário
bStream.type = 1

call bStream.Open()
call bStream.Write(nodeB64.NodeTypedValue)

' muda type pra text
bStream.position = 0
bStream.type = 2
bStream.charSet = "us-ascii"

call bStream.SaveToFile("C:\fotos\imagem.jpg", adSaveCreateOverWrite)
```

Comment: Sem sucesso. A primeira proposta gera o mesmo resultado e a última gera um erro.

Comment: @Onaiggac coloquei outra solução, fique atento a mudança dos type durante o processo