# Salvando Imagem base64 com ADODB.Stream e ASP clássico

Tags: asp, base64

Estou usando ASP Clássico e Javascript para carregar e cortar as imagens para o site.
Utilizo um script que converte  as imagens para base64 envia pelo post e é processado no servidor.

Segui o passo a passo por aqui: [Salvando Imagem base64 com ADODB.Stream](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66258/salvando-imagem-base64-com-adodb-stream/67439)

Prévia: http://codepen.io/bigaton/pen/NRBKaa

Acontece que quando dimensionado a minha imagem para um determinado tamanho ocorre erro ao salvar:

> msxml3.dll erro '80004005' Erro ao analisar 'bla bla img base64' como
>   tipo de dados bin.base64.

**save2.asp**

```
base64String = Trim(Request.Form("cropped2"))

response.write base64String

Set tmpDoc = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
Set nodeB64 = tmpDoc.CreateElement("b64")
nodeB64.DataType = "bin.base64"
nodeB64.Text = Mid(base64String, InStr(base64String, ",") + 1)

set bStream = server.CreateObject("ADODB.stream")

bStream.type = 1

call bStream.Open()

call bStream.Write(nodeB64.NodeTypedValue)

caminho=Server.MapPath("/teste/imagem.png")
call bStream.SaveToFile(caminho, 2)

call bStream.close()
set bStream = nothing
```

Imagens de até 550x400 salvam normalmente, 550x450 ocorre erro e acima desses valores também.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido. Ao invés de enviar a string base64 pelo POST do HTML ( onde eu carregava a string num campo oculto), envio pelo POST do AJAX.

```
   document.querySelector('#btnCrop').addEventListener('click', function(){
   var img = cropper.getDataURL()
   $.post('ajax/salvar2.asp', {imagem: img});
```

Esse post pode ser utilizado no PHP e no ASP.

**Exemplo salvar base64 em imagem ASP. (salvar2.asp)**

```
base64String = Trim(Request.Form("imagem"))
Set tmpDoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
Set nodeB64 = tmpDoc.CreateElement("b64")
nodeB64.DataType = "bin.base64"
nodeB64.Text = Mid(base64String, InStr(base64String, ",") + 1)
set bStream = server.CreateObject("ADODB.stream")
bStream.type = 1
call bStream.Open()
call bStream.Write(nodeB64.NodeTypedValue)
caminho=Server.MapPath("../caminho_salvaer/imagem.png")
call bStream.SaveToFile(caminho, 2)
call bStream.close()
set bStream = nothing
```

**salvar.php**

```
<?php

// Recuperando imagem em base64
// Exemplo: data:image/png;base64,AAAFBfj42Pj4
$imagem = $_POST['imagem'];

// Separando tipo dos dados da imagem
// $tipo: data:image/png
// $dados: base64,AAAFBfj42Pj4
list($tipo, $dados) = explode(';', $imagem);

// Isolando apenas o tipo da imagem
// $tipo: image/png
list(, $tipo) = explode(':', $tipo);

// Isolando apenas os dados da imagem
// $dados: AAAFBfj42Pj4
list(, $dados) = explode(',', $dados);

// Convertendo base64 para imagem
$dados = base64_decode($dados);

// Gerando nome aleatório para a imagem
$nome = md5(uniqid(time()));

// Salvando imagem em disco
file_put_contents("../img/{$nome}.jpg", $dados);
```